# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 ( python, mxnet)

Tags: python, mxnet, index-error

I am working in Mxnet for image classification. I loaded dataset with RecordFileDetection class. I want to print the shape of data and label. But it shows the error.

My code segment is:

```
  from gluoncv.data import RecordFileDetection
  train_data_loader=RecordFileDetection('/home/vj/
                    Desktop/example_rec.rec',coord_normalized=True)
  print(len(train_data_loader))
  data =train_data_loader[0][1]
  print(data.shape)
```

---

Traceout

### 939

```
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call 
 last)
 <ipython-input-70-3bc3bb8bd0b5> in <module>()
  2 
 train_data_loader=RecordFileDetection('/home/vj/
 Desktop/example_rec.rec',coord_normalized=True)
       3 print(len(train_data_loader))
 ----> 4 data =train_data_loader[0][1]
       5 print(data.shape)

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gluoncv/data/
recordio/detection.pyc in __getitem__(self, idx)
      71         h, w, _ = img.shape
      72         if self._coord_normalized:
 ---> 73             label = _transform_label(label, h, w)
      74         else:
      75             label = _transform_label(label)

 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
 packages/gluoncv/data/recordio/detection.pyc in 
 _transform_label(label, height, width)
       8     label = np.array(label).ravel()
       9     header_len = int(label[0])  # label header
 ---> 10     label_width = int(label[1])  # the label width for each 
                                                object, >= 5
      11     if label_width < 5:
      12         raise ValueError(

      IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I am not getting what is the error. Please kindly help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use the [instruction here](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/build/examples_datasets/detection_custom.html) to create you .rec file?

Comment: @K Vijayaprabakaran 
do you have a solution for this?